# Newsletter black background in IE

Tags: email, rendering, newsletter

As you can see the picture, i have a problem with Internet Explorer. I've tried to make the background color white on parent element. But it still doesn't work.

How can i fix that problem?

[image]

Comment: Code is here   
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/osbJq

Comment: There's no black background .. tested with jsfiddle too

Comment: the problem arises when I sent to mail. On Internet Explorer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The div that is giving you problems only has a 3-digit hex code. Try bgcolor="#FFFFFF" if it is Outlook that is giving you issues.

Comment: i'm changed #fff to #ffffff. Problem is fixed. Thanks